# How to stop scroll event when path application changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple photo gallery with infinite scroll. The problem is, when I clicked Link and change path, event still living an got me an errors.

App:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.scrollListener = window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll = () => {
  const { scrolling, totalPages, page } = this.state;
  if (scrolling || totalPages <= page) {
    return;
  }
  const lastPhoto = document.querySelector("section > div:last-child");
  const lastPhotoOffset = lastPhoto.offsetTop + lastPhoto.clientHeight;
  const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;
  const bottomOffset = 20;
  if (pageOffset > lastPhotoOffset - bottomOffset) {
    this.loadMorePhotos();
  }
```

and if the event happened at least once and I goes to the /photo/photo:id path, I've got an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null
const lastPhotoOffset = lastPhoto.offsetTop + lastPhoto.clientHeight;
```

i tried:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.handleScroll = null;
}
```

or:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.scrollListener = null;
}
```

But is doesn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove event listeners inside componentWillUnmount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, false);
}
```